# How do I call exec in psake to an executable with a variable path?

Tags: powershell, psake

I can't seem to call this executable correctly in my psake deploy script.

If I do this:

```
exec { "$ArchiverOutputDir\NServiceBus.Host.exe /install" }
```

It simply outputs this (and is clearly not calling the executable - just outputting the value of that expression):

```
c:\ReloDotNet2_ServiceEndpoints\Archiver\NServiceBus.Host.exe /install
```

But if I do this:

```
exec { c:\ReloDotNet2_ServiceEndpoints\Archiver\NServiceBus.Host.exe /install }
```

I get the expected output from the executable.

How do I correctly call an executable with a variable in the path to the executable in psake?  If this is actually a PowerShell issue, please feel free to correct the question to reflect that insight.

I

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Classic PowerShell issue. Try this instead:

```
exec { & "$ArchiverOutputDir\NServiceBus.Host.exe" /install }
```

PowerShell not only executes commands, it also evaluates expressions e.g.:

```
C:\PS> 2 + 2
4
C:\PS> "hello world"
hello world
```

What you have given to PowerShell at the beginning of a pipeline is a string expression which it faithfully evaluates and prints to the console.  By using the call operator `&`, you're telling PowerShell that the following thing is either the name of a command (in a string) to be executed or a scriptblock to be executed.  Technically you could also use `. "some-command-name-or-path"`.  The only difference is that for PowerShell commands, `&` creates a new scope to execute the command in and `.` doesn't.  For external exes it makes no difference as far as I can tell which one you use but `&` is typically used.